# Long running jobs redelivering after broker visibility timeout with celery and redis

Tags: redis, celery

I am using celery 4.3 + Redis + flower. I have a few long-running jobs with acks_late=True and task_reject_on_worker_lost=True. I am using celery grouping to group jobs run parallelly and append result and use in parent job.

In this scenario, my few jobs will run more than an hour, after every one hour the same child jobs are redelivering again to the worker.

The sample jobs as below.

```
@app.task(queue='q1', bind=True, acks_late=True, task_reject_on_worker_lost=True, max_retries=3)
def job_1(self):
  do_something()
  task_group = group(job_2.s(batch) for batch in range(0, len([1,2,3,4,5,6]), 3))
  result_group = task_group.apply_async()

@app.task(queue='q1', bind=True, acks_late=True, task_reject_on_worker_lost=True, max_retries=3)
def job_2(self, batch):
  do_something()
  return result
```

The above job_2 will run more than hour and after one hour the same is redelivering again to the worker.

My celery setup and config as shown below:

```
c = Celery(app.import_name,
           backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
           broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
```

config.py

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = os.environ['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = os.environ['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND']
CELERY_BROKER_TRANSPORT_OPTIONS = {'visibility_timeout': 36000}
```

I tried to increase visibility timeout to 10 hours after the redelivering issue like above in configuration. but it looks like not working.

Please help with this issue and let me know if any solution.

Comment: If I remove acks_late=True, it is working as expected but when worker is killed and active jobs are not going to another active worker if I remove the configuration.